# Opening Firefox via Selenium in Jenkins

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

When trying to run a Python Selenium script via Jenkins, it crashes, with a very unhelpful exception - **"selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status: 0"**
The same Python script runs perfectly fine from outside Python.

I've reduced the script to a very, very basic one, simply launching Firefox -

```
from selenium import webdriver

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Hello World")
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get("http://www.google.com")
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.quit()
    print("Goodbye World")
```

Output from cmd prompt:

```
>C:\Users\kipod>C:\python_projects\Ranger\_just_open_browser.py

>Hello World

>Goodbye World
```

Works fine.

Running as a Jenkins job:

```
>##Started by user anonymous
>Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Second Test
>[Second Test] $ cmd /c call >C:\Users\kipod\AppData\Local\Temp\jenkins3557827225974274191.bat
>
>C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Second Test>python >C:\python_projects\Ranger\_just_open_browser.py 
>Hello World
>Traceback (most recent call last):
>  File "C:\python_projects\Ranger\_just_open_browser.py", line 8, in <module>
>    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
>  File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site->packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 154, in __init__
>    keep_alive=True)
>  File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site->packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 151, in __init__
>    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
>  File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site->packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 240, in start_session
>    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
>  File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site->packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 308, in execute
>    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
>  File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site->packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
>    **raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly >closed with status: 0**


>C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Second Test>exit 1 
>Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
>Finished: FAILURE
```

I suspect something is off with Jenkins's environment variables, but I have no idea what to check. And the exception is so unspecific ("I crashed. lols"), That I found nothing helpful on Google. And I've been searching for a while.

Versions:
Jenkins: 2.73.1
Python:  3.6.2
Geckodriver: 0.19.0
Selenium: 3.6.0

(Tried opening chrome instead of firefox - same behaviour.)

Comment: how about locally, is it working. The last time i checked python 3.6 was not having that good support for webdriver, if you could, could you try on python 2.7

Comment: Thank you. Acts the same with 3.6 uninstalled and 2.7 installed.

Comment: Which version of selenium you are using ?

Comment: C:\Users\kipod>pip freeze
selenium==3.6.0

Comment: Take a look to this: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/466

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to run your python script using a jenkins slave configured to log on as a standard windows user account (for example "kipod") ? Make sure that auto login is set for the slave machine for the user account, in order to allow selenium to launch Firefox in a desktop.

Some documenation here: [Step by step guide to set up master and slave machines on Windows](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machines+on+Windows)